# benefits of using ssl in login

Tags: ssl

I found some sites using https:// for login page

https://login.alibaba.com/

What are the advantages of using ssl in a login page, also these guys are used a sub domain for login, why should I set a sub domain for login, is it another server for handling login process ?

How can I set https in my site ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that the login session will be over SSL/TLS and thus will be relatively secure, unless the user has a keylogger, or the Man In The Middle is not:

- A government agency
- The ISP.
- A large corporation.
- A master, highly motivated hacker.

Basically SSL certs protect you from anyone who the Root CA won't take money from.  These actors probably don't want the average users social networking login, so in practice that's pretty secure.

It's a great idea, really.  SSL the login page and the user/pass is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

As in any page you're transferring critical info, SSL;

- encrypts the transaction, so nobody between you and the website can listen/record the internet line for your important info, including people at your ISP and FBI.
- works as a signature of the domain owner, so you can trust the company name on the certificate is correct and the domain really belongs to them.

SSL certificates are given by trusted companies and certificates have levels. Green ones are harder to get; companies are inpected more by the certificate giver, so you can be sure the company is a valid one.

Subdomains are usually used because of how SSL works. SSL works on its own port and protocol (https), and multiple domains on a single IP won't work with SSL, so a secure server usually has its own IP and a single domain. In this case, 'login' host is a secure server, and that IP number can host only that subdomain securely.

Answer (score 1):

- Your password wont be hijacked from an eavesdroper
- It will show a lock / green status bar on the browsers so users will feel safe.

There could be many reasons to set up a sub-domain on your login page. I do not think you can read all that much into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you sent a password using http everyone on the way (a sniffer on every network component) can read it because it is sent as plain text.
https opens a secured end-to-end-channel. That means that your browser encrypt your data (e. g. your password) with the public key of the server. That lead to the result that noone except the server can decrypt it.

Tomka